# How to call block method from Controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, magento-2.0.7

I want call block methods from controller. My files are below

**Controller**

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
   public function __construct(Context $context) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
   }
}
```

**Layout**

**cms_index_index**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-left"> 
     <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block   class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\ProductTabs" name="producttabs" template="producttabs.phtml" ifconfig="form_section/form_group_general/status">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Block**

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;
class ProductTabs extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getMsg(){
      return 'i am in block';
    }
}
```

I want `getMsg()` to be accessed in controller. If anybody know then please share your experience.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Answer (score 6):

You can call directly in controller like this, In your controller file,

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

      public function execute()
            {
                $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
                $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('producttabs')->getMsg()
                return $resultLayout;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I  used your way but getting error and one more thing, I want getMsg() to be called from controller and you are calling toHtml(). Can you call  getMsg() and reply me. Now some part of error message what i am getting is **Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory, none given**

Comment: Remove var folder and check now

Comment: @Pinku Have you checked?

Comment: In var lots of folder are there so full folder need to delete or else any specific folder

Comment: you can delete full folder

Comment: I have deleted var folder but after that i am getting error is **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMsg() on boolean in /var/www/html/magento21/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Index/Index.php:78 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento21/var/generation/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24):.....
**

Comment: have you resolve your issue?

Comment: Not yet @Rakesh. I am getting error  Which was i mentioned above.

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 3):

You can access your block method like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;


class Index extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout = $this->_resultLayoutFactory->create();
        $block = $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('producttabs');
        if ($block) {
            $msg = $block->getMsg();
        }

    }
}
```

Here `$msg` will hold `getMsg()` output.

Comment: Not working....